# How to make PyCharm scroll bars and window borders darker and thinner?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I just upgraded to PyCharm 3.4 (on a new computer with Mavericks) from 3.1 (and Snow Leopard).

I've imported my settings from the old PyCharm installation and all looks and works the same – EXCEPT the panel scroll bars and borders are (1) a much lighter shade of gray and (2) thicker.

How can I make them darker and thinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elevators/scroll-bars are not configurable. The only way to change them is to change the overall Look and Feel theme setting via Settings > [IDE Settings] > Appearance > "UI Options" > Theme.

Comment: Thanks. On PyCharm 3.4 on OS X, the exact setting is Preferences > Appearance (under the list of IDE Settings) > Theme (under the UI Options section). Set it to "Darcula" instead of "Default."